# Python: Handling exceptions while sorting

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of objects that I need to sort according to a [key function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#Key_Functions). The problem is that some of the elements in my list can go "out-of-date" while the list is being sorted. When the key function is called on such an expired item, it fails with an exception.

Ideally, what I would like is a way of sorting my list with a key function such that when an error occurs upon calling the key function on an element, this element is excluded from the sort result.

My problem can be reconstructed using the following example: Suppose I have two classes, `Good` and `Bad`:

```
class Good(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Good(%r)' % self.x

class Bad(object):
    @property
    def x(self):
        raise RuntimeError()
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Bad'
```

I want to sort instances of these classes according to their `x` property. Eg.:

```
>>> sorted([Good(5), Good(3), Good(7)], key=lambda obj: obj.x)
[Good(3), Good(5), Good(7)]
```

Now, when there is a `Bad` in my list, the sorting fails:

```
>>> sorted([Good(5), Good(3), Bad()], key=lambda obj: obj.x)
... RuntimeError
```

I am looking for a magical function `func` that sorts a list according to a key function, but simply ignores elements for which the key function raised an error:

```
>>> func([Good(5), Good(3), Bad()], key=lambda obj: obj.x)
[Good(3), Good(5)]
```

What is the most Pythonic way of achieving this?

Comment: Does `Bad.x` really raise a `RuntimeError` when asked for or does it simply raise an `AttributeError`?

Comment: I'm curious as to why your objects expire. Is it another thread, modifying your objects while you sort? Or do they literally expire due to the passage of time? But then, why would that make the attribute raise an Exception? For instance, it's not sensible to make the attribute `Apple.age` raise a `TooOldException`.

Comment: @Kevin, the objects expire because they represent (Selenium) web elements in an open browser window (=another process). If eg. the page reloads while the list is being sorted, then at least some elements of the list raise Selenium `StaleElementReferenceExceptions` when accessing their attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the result of the key function can change over time, and most sorting implementations probably assume a deterministic key function, it's probably best to only execute the key function once per object, to ensure a well-ordered and crash-free final list.

```
def func(seq, **kargs):
    key = kargs["key"]
    stored_values = {}
    for item in seq:
        try:
            value = key(item)
            stored_values[item] = value
        except RuntimeError:
            pass
    return sorted(stored_values.iterkeys(), key=lambda item: stored_values[item])


print func([Good(5), Good(3), Bad()], key=lambda obj: obj.x)
```

Result:

```
[Good(3), Good(5)]
```

Comment: This is a great idea, but it removes duplicate items from the list: `good_5 = Good(5) ; print func([good_5, Good(3), good_5, Bad()], key=lambda obj: obj.x)`. Nevertheless, I will go with an approach along those lines. Thanks!

Comment: That bare except: is probably not a good idea. You might hide more exceptions than intended.

Answer (score 2):

Every sorting algorithm I know doesn't throw out some values because they're outdated or something. The task of sorting algorithm is to **sort** the list, and sort it fast, everything else is extraneous, specific task.
So, I would write this magical function myself. It would do the sorting in two steps: first it would filter the list, leaving only `Good` values, and then sort the resulting list.

Comment: I see your point, but sorting in two steps is not an option. It seems the `Good` and `Bad` example is too contrived. As I stated in the first paragraph of my question, the list items can go from `Good` to `Bad` while the list is being sorted. Clearing out all `Good` items before sorting thus cannot guarantee that no exception will occur during the subsequent sort.

Comment: @MichaelHerrmann I see. Well, than the only option is to write the sorting algorithm with this specific functionality yourself, as dstrmoberg proposed.

Answer (score 2):

I did this once with a mergesort.  Mergesort makes it relatively simple to eliminate no-longer-useful values.

The project I did it in is at http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~dstromberg/equivalence-classes.html#python-3e .  Feel free to raid it for ideas, or lift code out of it; it's Free as in speech (GPLv2 or later, at your option).

The sort in that code should almost do what you want, except it'll sort a list with duplicates to a list of lists, where each sublist has equal values.  That part may or may not be useful to you.

I've got a more straightforward mergesort (it doesn't do the duplicate buckets thing, but it doesn't deal with dropping no-longer-good values either) at http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/svn/sorts/compare/trunk/ .  The file is .m4, but don't let that fool you - it's really pure python or cython autogenerated from the same .m4 file.

Answer (score 0):

If the list items can go from Good to Bad while sorting, then there is nothing you can do. The `key`s are evaluated only once before sorting, so any change in the key will be invisible to the sort function:

```
>>> from random import randrange
>>> values = [randrange(100) for i in range(10)]
>>> values
[54, 72, 91, 73, 55, 68, 21, 25, 18, 95]
>>> def k(x):
...   print x
...   return x
... 
>>> values.sort(key=k)
54
72
91
73
55
68
21
25
18
95
```

(If the key were evaluated many times during the sort, you would see the numbers printed many times).